# if the most-significant bit of most-significant byte is 1, then sample is negative

Tags: c++, audio, wav

Hi I am doing a project  on audio processing

The code works fine but I don’t understand these three lines

If anyone knows something about what these lines of code say

```cpp
// Otherwise, if the most-significant bit of most-significant byte is 1, then
// sample is negative, so we need to set the upper bytes to all 1s.
else if (sampleBytes[bytesPerSample-1] & 0x80)
{
    for (size_t b = bytesPerSample; b < sizeof(sample); b++)
    {
        sampleBytes[b] = 0xFF;
    }
}
```

Comment: What specifically don't you understand?  What is the type of `sampleBytes`?  Are you asking about how negatives are represented in binary (_e.g._ two's complement)?  Or are you asking about the actual test using bitwise-AND?

Comment: Off-hand, this snippet appears to be part of a larger code that handles audio samples as raw bytes, and is probably in the middle of logic to upscale samples to a larger byte size, say from 2 bytes per sample to 4 bytes, and in this case is sign-extending negative samples to preserve their numeric values in the new size.

Answer (score 0):

That lines extend the number with 'bytesPerSample' bytes placed in 'sampleBytes' to as many bytes as 'sample' variable by completing with ones if it is negative.

In most systems, negative numbers are binary represented in two complement form (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). That is, -x  = NOT(x) + 1.

```
For example:
11111111 = 1
11111110 = 2
11111101 = 3
11111100 = 4
...
```

So if the number is negative, it must be completed with ones to be extended maintaining the value.

The first line asserts if the number is negative, the second iterate by the extra bytes, and the last put the ones in hexadecimal.